# Somar o count em uma consulta

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer a soma de um count em uma consulta que retorna três colunas no oracle
sendo a coluna total_dieta a contagem de eventos para aquele grupo!

| NM_DIETA | TOTAL_DIETA | DS_SETOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Extra: fruta | 4 | ANEXO A |
| Dieta Livre ou Geral | 2 | ANEXO A |

```
SELECT
  
    D.NM_DIETA,
    count(*) total_dieta,
    /*sum(count(*)) total  adicionar o total da contagem*/,
    obter_ds_setor_atendimento(s.cd_setor_atendimento) DS_SETOR
FROM 
    ATENDIMENTO_PACIENTE_V V
INNER JOIN CPOE_DIETA C ON (V.NR_ATENDIMENTO = C.NR_ATENDIMENTO)
INNER JOIN DIETA D ON (C.CD_DIETA = D.CD_DIETA)
INNER JOIN SETOR_ATENDIMENTO S ON (V.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO = S.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO)
WHERE S.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO LIKE UPPER(:CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO)

AND V.DT_ALTA IS NULL
and c.dt_suspensao is null
and (c.dt_fim>sysdate or c.dt_fim is null)
GROUP BY 
    D.NM_DIETA,
    obter_ds_setor_atendimento(s.cd_setor_atendimento)
        
ORDER BY total_dieta desc
```

Recebo a seguinte informação:
ORA-00937: não é uma função de grupo de grupo simples

Como poderei adicionar a coluna total da contagem?

| NM_DIETA | TOTAL_DIETA | DS_SETOR | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Extra: fruta | 4 | ANEXO A | 6 |
| Dieta Livre ou Geral | 2 | ANEXO A | 6 |

Comment: Use OVER https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/count-analytic-function

Comment: o count(*) over () me retorna o total de linhas 2 e não o total 6

Comment: ... PARTITION BY ...

Comment: @Motta SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS total_count resolveu a questão! obrigado

Comment: Publica a solução , pode ajudar outrem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução simples com utilização do OVER()

```
SELECT
  
    D.NM_DIETA,
    count(*) total_dieta,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() total,
    obter_ds_setor_atendimento(s.cd_setor_atendimento) DS_SETOR
FROM 
    ATENDIMENTO_PACIENTE_V V
INNER JOIN CPOE_DIETA C ON (V.NR_ATENDIMENTO = C.NR_ATENDIMENTO)
INNER JOIN DIETA D ON (C.CD_DIETA = D.CD_DIETA)
INNER JOIN SETOR_ATENDIMENTO S ON (V.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO = S.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO)
WHERE S.CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO LIKE UPPER(:CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO)

AND V.DT_ALTA IS NULL
and c.dt_suspensao is null
and (c.dt_fim>sysdate or c.dt_fim is null)
GROUP BY 
    D.NM_DIETA,
    obter_ds_setor_atendimento(s.cd_setor_atendimento)
        
ORDER BY total_dieta desc
```

Resultado:

| NM_DIETA | TOTAL_DIETA | DS_SETOR | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Extra: fruta | 4 | ANEXO A | 6 |
| Dieta Livre ou Geral | 2 | ANEXO A | 6 |